# VBA, copying and pasting rows, from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I am trying to copy rows from one worksheet and paste them on another worksheet if they match a specific criterion, but I am struggling with the copy and paste functions of VBA. Could someone help me out please?

```
Sub Code()

Dim x, y As Range

Number_of_rows_ORIGIN = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).EntireColumn)

For Each x In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Number_of_rows_ORIGIN, 3))

    Nb_R_Dest = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 3).EntireColumn)

    If x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(x.Row).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Nb_R_Dest + 1, 1).Paste
    Else
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to copy values. I've tweaked a bit your code to make it look cleaner:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Code()

    Dim x As Range, LastRow As Long, LastRowPaste As Long
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook 'use this to shorten your code
        Set ws = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsSource = .Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set wsPaste = .Sheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    LastRow = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'This is cleaner to get the last row

    For Each x In Range(ws.Cells(1, 3), ws.Cells(LastRow, 3))
        LastRowPaste = wsPaste.Cells(wsPaste.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If x = wsSource.Cells(1, 1) Then
            wsPaste.Rows(LastRowPaste).Value = wsSource.Rows(x.Row).Value
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it help, don't forget to mark as an answer so someone might find it usefull